# Error in AppleScript for iMessage - Can’t get service of text chat id

Tags: applescript, imessage

I get the error: Can’t get service of text chat id "iMessage;-;". (-1728) - when trying to send a text to another imessage client on a mac (different user). Here is the code fragment where it is failing:

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received theText from theBuddy for theChat
        # get what we need
        set recvService to name of service of theChat
```

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: As explained below, the behavior observed is a *bug*. However, the OP himself found a workaround: the `from` argument of the `message received` event (`theBuddy` in the sample code) is an instance of the `Buddy` class, which *also* has a `service` property, which functions correctly:

```applescript
set recvService to name of service of theBuddy # instead of the buggy `of theChat`
```

<sup>Note: The `message received` event's `for` parameter (`theChat` in the OP's code) is an instance of the `text chat` class, which inherits from the `chat` base class. If the Dictionary Viewer in Script Editor isn't configured to show *inherited* items, it will not be obvious by looking at the `text chat` class that it indeed does have a - currently buggy - `service` property. To make inherited items visible, open Script Editor's Preferences dialog and check `Show inherited items`.</sup>

---

**It appears there's a bug** in the AppleScript support for `Messages.app` (observed on OSX 10.11.1); I suggest you file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com; here's a simple demonstration:

```applescript
tell application "Messages"

    set svc to first item of services

    set cht to first item of (chats of svc)

    # !! Breaks, even though it should return the same object as `svc`.
    # "Can’t get service of text chat id \"iMessage;-;<recipient>\"."
    service of cht 

end tell
```

It seems that trying to access *any* property of a `text chat` instance is currently broken.

You can try a **workaround:**

```applescript
# Given a chat instance, returns its originating service.
on getService(cht)
    local svc, cht
    tell application "Messages"
        repeat with svc in services
            try
                (first chat of svc whose it is cht)
                return contents of svc
            end try
        end repeat
    end tell
    return missing value
end getService

# Sample invocation
set recvService to name of (my getService(theChat))
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, just an update and maybe an explanation(?):

```
set recvService to name of service of theChat - fails.
set recvService to name of service of theBuddy - works.
```

In looking at the dictionary for messages.app, it seems that there is no "service" for chat but there is for buddy.

I've only begun scripting in El Capitan so I don't know if this is a change or a bug. I'll leave that to others more experienced to comment.

Since I can get the service from the "buddy", I don't need mklement0's answer (but I'm very grateful for the response) so I'll leave things as they are for now.

Comment: I'm glad you found a workaround. The `text chat` class - of which `theChat` in your code is an instance - _does_ have a `service` property, which it _inherits_ from the ancestral `chat` class. Generally, you won't see the inherited items in the Dictionary Viewer unless you check `Show inherited items` in its Preferences dialog. So your original issue _is_ a bug. If there were no such property, you'd see a _different_ error message (`can't make ... into type specifier`).

Comment: I've updated my answer with your findings and my comments. Btw, if you want me to be notified of a response, you'll have to comment on _my_ answer.